# I pushed directly to the develop branch without pull request how do I undo it?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-revert

I am trying to cancel all the commit pushed by james plus getting his commits on my local and go back to the commit pushed by brandon which is

```
d65fa2faf06a5c4d8d379f963feece2bf2edef98.
```

I tried doing

```
git revert a586cc1ff0c5abf535a4d0873c458a812dca28dd..1dcc0e8adc5433a5b092e3b813496ac52de7aa43
```

-- but for some unknown reasons it throws me this error

```
    hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

and at the end it only reverts `1dcc0e8adc5433a5b092e3b813496ac52de7aa43`

here is my git log of the develop branch

```
commit 1dcc0e8adc5433a5b092e3b813496ac52de7aa43 (origin/develop, feat_SS_250.fixes)
Author: <james@ueharanoMacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Tue Feb 5 17:50:20 2019 +0900

    schema added

commit fee01a2dcf3432b7da6e9e6b1ff030ad288d919d
Author: <james@ueharanoMacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Tue Feb 5 17:48:49 2019 +0900

    rebase

commit 7f226d84029e608721417b8e99be1a88c6ae3a84
Author: <james@ueharanoMacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Tue Feb 5 16:03:07 2019 +0900

    initial commit

commit a586cc1ff0c5abf535a4d0873c458a812dca28dd
Author: <james@ueharanoMacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Thu Jan 24 11:42:08 2019 +0900

    added login.php

commit d65fa2faf06a5c4d8d379f963feece2bf2edef98
Author: brandon <brandon@xxxx.co.jp>
Date:   Tue Feb 5 14:52:04 2019 +0900

    feat: fp 50

commit 9988b6587f9e2fa77d86e9e1f856bf57e667daca
Author: brandon <brandon@xxxx.co.jp>
Date:   Tue Feb 5 14:25:51 2019 +0900

    feat: contract 50
```

Comment: Is rewinding `HEAD` back to commit `d65fa2faf06a5c4d8d379f963feece2bf2edef98` and `force` `push`'ing `origin develop` back to that state an option?

Comment: Is rewriting history available in your workflow? If so, `git reset --hard d65fa2f` then push it with `-f`. Then again, it's maybe not on the table due to your specific context.

Comment: @RomainValeri hehe, by seconds. My thought exactly.

Comment: I just want to go back to brandons last commit without the log of james (me) accidentally pushing my commits , if that is possible.

Comment: Right now it is in the middle of the night here so my push is the latest commit now so I think I am safe to go back to brandons last commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ...

```
git reset --hard d65fa2f
git push -f origin develop
```

**Note**: would suggest that you take a backup of your remote before `force` pushing any changes. Also, if someone has pulled the branch which has James changes they are subject to receive errors next time they try to `pull` the branch.

Comment: will I still get my changes to my local ?

Comment: @Johji I don't see any of your changes in the `git log`. The answer will `force` reset `origin develop` to Brandon's commit (overwriting the `log`). You can do it in a temporary directory outside of your current working directory (i.e. `cd /tmp/foo`, `git init .`, `git remote add origin ...`, `git checkout -b develop`, `git pull origin develop`, `git reset --hard d65fa2f`, `git push -f origin develop`). That way you're certain it won't touch anything in your current local working directory.

Comment: my changes are from a586cc1ff0c5abf535a4d0873c458a812dca28dd to 1dcc0e8adc5433a5b092e3b813496ac52de7aa43. I got my changes by doing git reset --hard d65fa2f then git diff 1dcc0e8adc5433a5b092e3b813496ac52de7aa43 which gets my commits and place it to file.

Comment: in order for me to delete the logs properly should I make a new branch before doing what you tell me or should I just do it directly in develop branch without creating new branch from develop branch ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, may be I would do in this way:

**(01) Reset a number of last commits and keep the commits as staged:**

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~<num_of_commit_from_HEAD>
$ git status
$ git log
$ git push -f origin <branch_name>
```

Here, in your case `num_of_commit_from_HEAD` = `4` and `branch_name` = `develop`.

**(02) Reset a number of last commits and remove the commits:**

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~<num_of_commit_from_HEAD>
$ git status
$ git log
$ git push -f origin <branch_name>
```

Here, in your case `num_of_commit_from_HEAD` = `4` and `branch_name` = `develop`.